# Why my memory has 18 digits addresses? D:

Tags: pointers

I was programming following a tutorial and when I was in the pointer tutorial I notice that the output of thsi code is so much larger than the normal (it is ptr = 0x000000cd9d1cf504) :/ why?

```
int main()
{

    int pointerTest = 6;
    void* ptr = 0; 
    ptr = &pointerTest;
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Please define "normal" and why you expect that, and then think to mention which operating system and compiler you are using.

Comment: You are compiling for 64bit, while tutorial was using 32 bit I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an 18-digit address - it only consists of 16 digits. The prefix `0x` merely indicates that what comes after it is going to be in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) form. The other commonly used notation for hexadecimal integers is `h` (or sometimes `x`, such as in VHDL) either prefixed or postfixed (for example `hCD9D1CF504`, `h'CD9D1CF504` or `CD9D1CF504h` - note that this is quite unclear unless the hexadecimal digits A-F are capitalized).

One hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits, so the pointer is 4 * 16 = 64 bits in size. In other words, the binary executable produced by your compiler is 64-bit, while the tutorial binary likely was 32-bit, as pointed out by @Hawky in the comments.

To fully understand the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit code, you'll have to study computer architecture, the x86-64 in particular. Be warned, though - if you choose to go down that route, prepare for a lifetime of pain and suffering (the worst bit being that you might just enjoy it).